# I have date stored in the format mm/dd/yyyy but i need to view as August 22nd, 2014

Tags: sql, oracle

I have date stored in format mm/dd/yyyy in the database, but I need to view as Month Date(with superscript), Year. I am using Oracle 11g

Comment: My suggestion is to view in this format on application level.

Comment: Date storage in databases should be independent of the display format.  Check your database column, and make sure it's an actual date, not a string.

Comment: i am getting in the required format using to_char(mydate, 'Month DD, YYYY') but I am not able to get the suffix(nd,rd, etc). Thanks in advance

Comment: @RobertHarvey 2**nd**, 3**rd**, etc.

Comment: 22nd, 23rd, 9th. The datatype is already date but the date is inserted only in the format mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: But it's not stored in mm/dd/yyyy. The insertion format is irrelevant to how it's stored.

Comment: Your display technology should already have formatting for such things.  For example, in C#, you would say something like `Console.WriteLine(thisDate.ToString("D"));`  The `D` indicates Long Date format.

Comment: The main issue is to view the date along with the suffix. @RobertHarvey I searched for your suggestion http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx but it also does'nt show the suffix.

Comment: That's just an example.  It only works if you're actually using C# and the .NET Framework (unlikely, if you're using Oracle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returned date can be manipulated as part of the query.
Example:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(ts_col, 'DD-MON-YYYY') FROM date_tab;
```

The format string you would probably want is: `'MONTH DDTH, YYYY'`

I would advise to just take whatever format the database gives you and handle it client-side though.

More information about [TO_CHAR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm) can be found in the oracle docs. A full list of format models can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm). There is also [Datetime Format Element Suffixes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#BABGDDFB) allowing for 2nd, 3rd, etc.

Comment: @user3393415 seriously, though, don't do this. As Grice, Robert, Sarz and I have all said, you should be handling this client-side. Doing it in SQL is a terrible hack and just teaching you how to code badly.

Answer (score 5):

The database just stores dates, in an internal format. It doesn't store them in mm/dd/yyyy, or anything human-readable.

You are sending them to the database in mm/dd/yyyy format, by the sound of things; but how you display them is down to your client application. You should be retrieving them from the database, and then formatting them at the client end.

In other words, don't do this in SQL at all.

Answer (score -1):

heres a work around if you want ... i dont know if this exactly what you want

```
SELECT REPLACE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MonthDD,YYYY'),',','nd,') FROM DUAL;
```